# Java Android - Dividers already disabled but still shown

Tags: java, android, listview, divider

I'm using a custom list view here and already disabled the dividers for the list view.

I also tried on the normal listview (not a custom one) but it still didn't worked. Is there any ways beside modifying it from the xml?

Here's the code for the listview xml

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:showDividers="none"
tools:context=".MainActivity" >

<ListView
    android:id="@+id/lvListItem"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:divider="@null"
    android:dividerHeight="0px" >
</ListView>
```

Could someone help me get rid of the divider? :) Thanks!

Comment: A little suggestion: setting layout_weight in a listView can have a significant performance impact. Try to get rid of it or switch to a RelativeLayout

Answer (score 1):

Set the dividerHeight to zero and divider to null like this in xml:

```
android:dividerHeight="0dp"
android:divider="@null"
```

notice that `0dp` not `0px`.
Hope it works

Comment: Already tried that, but still.. hahaa I'm so curious about this.

Comment: you should change your android:layout_width="0dp" to wrap_contant or match_parent . or remove everything and start again from scratch